# Failing to generate a filter on debezium connector with error: "op is not a valid field name"

Tags: mysql, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I have created a debezium connector to a docker MySQL container.
I tried to set a filter for messages:

```
    {
        "name": "my_connector",
        "config": {
            "name": "my_connector",
            "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
            
            ...
            
            "include.schema.changes": "true",
            "transforms": "filter, unwrap",
            "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
            "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
            "transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
            "transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
            "transforms.filter.condition": "value.source.table == 'table-name' && (value.op == 'd' || value.op == 'c' || (value.op == 'u' && value.after.status != value.before.status))"
        }
    }
```

In `http://localhost:8070/connectors/my_connector/status` I see this:

> {
> "connector":
> {
> "state": "RUNNING",
> "worker_id": "172.21.0.13:8083"
> },
> "name": "my_connector",
> "tasks":
> [
> {
> "id": 0,
> "state": "FAILED",
> "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded
> in error handler\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:320)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:245)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\nCaused by:
> io.debezium.DebeziumException: Error while evaluating expression
> 'value.source.table == 'subscription_contract' && (value.op == 'd' ||
> value.op == 'c' || (value.op == 'u' && value.after.status !=
> value.before.status))' for record
> 'SourceRecord{sourcePartition={server=subscription_contracts_db   },
> sourceOffset={file=binlog.000006, pos=19704, snapshot=true}}
> ConnectRecord{topic='subscription_contracts_db', kafkaPartition=0,
> key=Struct{databaseName=subscription-contracts},
> keySchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.mysql.SchemaChangeKey:STRUCT},
> value=Struct{source=Struct{version=1.2.0.Final,connector=mysql,name=subscription_contracts_db,ts_ms=0,snapshot=true,db=subscription-contracts,table=subscription_contract,server_id=0,file=binlog.000006,pos=19704,row=0},databaseName=subscription-contracts,ddl=DROP
> TABLE IF EXISTS `subscription-contracts`.`subscription_contract`},
> valueSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.mysql.SchemaChangeValue:STRUCT},
> timestamp=null, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)}'\n\tat
> io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:116)\n\tat
> io.debezium.transforms.Filter.doApply(Filter.java:33)\n\tat
> io.debezium.transforms.ScriptingTransformation.apply(ScriptingTransformation.java:189)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)\n\t...
> 11 more\nCaused by: javax.script.ScriptException:
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field
> name\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)\n\tat org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71)\n\tat
> java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89)\n\tat
> io.debezium.transforms.scripting.Jsr223Engine.eval(Jsr223Engine.java:107)\n\t...
> 16 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op
> is not a valid field name\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.lookupField(Struct.java:254)\n\tat
> org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct.get(Struct.java:74)\n\tat
> jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown
> Source)\n\tat
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)\n\tat
> groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:62)\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)\n\tat
> Script9.run(Script9.groovy:1)\n\tat
> org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)\n\t... 19 more\n",
> "worker_id": "172.21.0.13:8083"
> }
> ],
> "type": "source" }

As [OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) pointed out, the basic issue here is:

> Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: op is not a valid field name\n\tat

But I am not sure what is wrong with using it, since it seems like it
is supposed to be a valid field - [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html).

Comment: The real error is `op is not a valid field name`.

Comment: From what I see here: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html it does seem like a valid field name.

Comment: Those docs don't use two transforms, though... I'd guess it's a bug since the filter transform should happen before the extraction one. But the extraction one removes the `op` field, so that would explain the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I've seemed to find the answer, hope it'd help someone else;

In my connector configurations I had this configuration:

```
"include.schema.changes": "true"
```

Which caused my connector to include also logs about schema changes in the DB table.
I have a docker container of a migrator initiating the DB container by running some flyway migrations, one of them is the `DROP TABLE` in my exception above.
Since schema change message has no reason to contain an `op` field it just doesn't (as shown in the example [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html)).
When the filter tries to fetch the field it doesn't find it and throws an exception.
Changing the configuration to `false` solved the issue.

Comment: by default it is given as true. I don't have it in my config but hope it solves mine problem too.

Comment: Not sure what is your issue, but be aware that what solved my issue is adding `"include.schema.changes": "false"` in my configurations.